# AWS not allowing me to add another ACM Certificate for SSL configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, aws-application-load-balancer, aws-acm-certificate

I am trying to add SSL Certificate in ALB, but getting following error.
[image]

I have requested successful 1 ACM Certificate, but unfortunately that was wrongly configured, and this issue is repeating after deleted my first ACM Certificate. Does AWS not allow to create multiple ACM Certificates ?, I dint found edit option to change `FQDN` hence I have to delete old cert

What is probable root cause, I tried to connect support team unfortunately ticket is still open.

Answer (score 2):

As per [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-failed.html)

> ACM requires additional information to process this certificate request. This happens as a fraud-protection measure if your domain ranks within the Alexa top 1000 websites. To provide the required information, use the Support Center to contact AWS Support. If you don't have a support plan, post a new thread in the ACM Discussion Forum.

In my view [ [only possible solution](https://repost.aws/questions/QU6kkV4uQzTVudnpKNg5G7pg/additional-verification-required) ]

> All Amazon certificates for these domains will remain functional until expiration, but will not be renewable and no new certificates from these domains will be issued. The only workaround that would work in your scenario would be to obtain a certificate from a third party that can issue a certificate for your domain, and import the certificate into ACM

Comment: Thats the miracle, because even after deleting the old certs, it is failing all the time while requesting a new certs, I guess AWS doesnt do hard delete. but then this is major problems.

Comment: Try changing the domain name for your verification =, I am sure they issue new certificate for different domain name. As I said, it will exist until expiration and you cant issue new certificate for this domain, if your domain falls in the range of Alexa top 1000 websites. If my answer helped you, can you accept it as solution so that it can help others in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

Contacting Support is recommended to resolve the issue as explained in this [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-failed.html#failed-additional-verification-required). Also, it's not possible to change domain names when a certificate has been requested and you can create multiple certificates in ACM.